# Difference between passing integer as reference and structure as reference in C

Tags: c

Code1:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void change(int *);

void main()
{
  int i=5;
  change(&i); 
  printf("The number has changed to:%d\n",i);
}

void change(int *a)
{
  *a=*a+5;
}
```

Code2:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

struct terms
{
  int coeff;
  int expo;
};

struct poly
{
  struct terms t[SIZE];
  int noofterms;
};

void initpoly(struct poly *);

void main()
{
  struct poly p1;
  initpoly(&p1);
}

void initpoly(struct poly *p)
{
  *p->noofterms=0;
}
```

In code1 if I want to change the value of variable `i`, I have to change through `*a=*a+5` but when I do the same thing in code2 it gives error. What's the difference?

Comment: i tried that and its working.But i want to know why its not working with *p like in code1.

Comment: C does not support pass by reference. It is strictly pass by value - no execptions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the usual way of dereferencing a pointer is with the dereference operator `*`, an additional dereference operator `->` is available only for `struct`s and `union`s. It combines the asterisk and a dot - in effect, `pointer->field` is the same as `(*pointer).field`.

Hence, the asterisk in front of `p` is no longer necessary, because operator `->` already provides pointer dereference:

```
p->noofterms=0;
```

Comment: @CroCo Then you need to add a dereference for that as well: `*(p->intPointerField) = 123;`